# Can Qt Create Blender-like GUI?

Tags: css, qt, user-interface, styles, blender

I am a newbie in Qt and was wondering if Qt or Qt Quick can be used to create a GUI similar to [Blender 3D](https://www.blender.org/), as shown in the following image. Are there other development tools that can do this? I would appreciate it if I could get any help or hint.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah.

Here Qt GUI: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/pix/idalarge.gif

It means that you can make complex GUI with Qt.

But You want "GUI like Blender". Ok. See styles example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-styles-example.html

P.S.: You can try Blendish (not Qt, glfw): https://bitbucket.org/duangle/oui-blendish/src

Comment: In your experience, can Blendish be integrated with Qt?

Comment: No. You can use Blendish without Qt, only pure C/C++. If You want use Qt - use Qt styles for copy Blender desing.